# Как правильнее писать: "Будьте себе благодарными", "Будьте к себе благодарными" или всё-таки "Будьте себе благодарны"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Чтобы передать мысль о благодарном отношении к себе и своему труду, вложениям и усилиям, как правильнее будет написать: "Будьте к себе благодарными", "Будьте себе благодарными", или всё-таки "Будьте себе благодарны". Последнее мне кажется не передаёт этой идеи, а в первых двух случая не понимаю какая форма была бы правильной.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

А какой смысл в этой фразе, каким образом можно быть благодарным по отношению к себе? Кто благодарен по отношению к себе, как этот кто-то называется? Обычно в таких случаях говорят, цените свой труд и цените себя(в смысле цените "своё"). Нет, ну можно, конечно, любой глагол ставит в конструкцию, но смысла это не привит. Вот фраза "будьте благодарны к себе(во всех вариантах)" - это какая-то чепуха. И смысла от изменения на "быть благодарным к своему" - тоже не прибавляется.

Например, можно сказать "подойти к дому", но если сказать "входить к дому" - то получается какая-то чепуха.

Comment: Даже если предположить, что "благодарить" себя не запрещается (может, это психология какая),  то смысл идеи от грамматики трех вариантов (правильных или неправильных) никак не зависит. А грамматика и стилистика фразы весьма сомнительны. Да и  сама идея как-то не просматривается...

Comment: @Sharon потому что это рунглиш, идет от фраз типа "Thank yourself", где thank это to reward, поощряй себя, одобряй свои действия, то есть буквально "молодец - возьми с полки пирожок", разрешай себе отмечать пирожком то, что считаешь правильным, подкрепляй правильное поведение положительными знаковыми дополнениями.

Тут отдельный вопрос, а что именно считать правильным, но это уже к западным индивидам.

Comment: Спасибо! Все-таки знание языков – это очень полезная вещь.

Comment: @Sharon да это не от знания, как раз наоборот, смотрю на фразу и не знаю, а в чем собственно смысл? начинаешь прикидывать, а концы не сходятся, придется лезть в логику другого языка, где начинает прослеживаться некий смысл. У языков нет стандартной логики, логика у языков(языковых групп) разная, то что логично в одном, в другом, если просто переводить слова, может звучать как чепуха, ну либо нужно вообще всю логику языка сломать и сделать нейкий стандартный, вроде эсперанто, правда смысла в речи на таком языке не будет, только семантика и значения. Как-то так я себе представляю этот процесс.

Comment: @Sharon в английском используются два слова для "смысла" sense и mean, точнее русское слово смысл(с мыслью, то есть отсылка к речи, потому что речь есть выражение мыслей в языковых формах), переводят и как sense  и как mean. Mean - это значение, а sense - это чувство, я бы перевел как "звучание". Вот у фразы может быть значение, а звучания нет - связки с опытом и образами нет, полная абстракция, оторванная от реальной жизни. Можно вспомнить басню про слона, когда слепые трогали слона и пытались обозначить то, что они чувствуют, кто-то говорил метла, трогая хвост, кто-то столб - ногу.

Comment: @Sharon но слон из всего этого не собирался, потому что слепые имеют сложности с дифференциацией первичного опыта, зрительный опыт более фундаментальный, тем слух/слухи. Вот слепые повторяют слова по слуху, а не по зрительному образу, в итоге они не могут собрать из известных частей - швабры, колонны и прочего, - целого слона. Потому что они не знают что есть слон, у них нет слова слон в речевом аппарате, а образа тоже нет, потому что они не видят слона.

Comment: Из частей целое не собирается. В этом смысл стандартизации, разбить структуру на такие части, чтобы не было возможности осознать целостную структуру. А раз нет понимания целого, то нет и вопросов. Каждый кусок по себе логичен, а всё вместе, целое - бессмысленно. Каждый кусок логичен в рамках формальной логики, стройностью которой славится англосаксонская культура, но целое не собирается или ложно. Однако доказать то, что целое ложно, через частности не представляется возможным. Это предел познания через формальную логику, через частности и признаки нельзя понять или оценить целое. Как-то так.

Comment: Нравятся мне ваши тексты, очень интересно их читать. Только вот жаль, что в виде комментариев они не очень заметны, вас бы могли  по достоинству оценить многие читатели. А у вас есть  какой-нибудь ресурс, где вы печатаете свои статьи (на какие-нибудь общие темы)?

Comment: @Sharon нет, но когда напишу книгу, я постараюсь дать вам знать)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно и так и так и так.

Немного остановимся на [разнице](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/polnaya-i-kratkaya-forma-prilagatelnyh) между кратким и полным прилагательным

> Напомним, что полные формы прилагательных выражают постоянные качества, абсолютные признаки, которые свойственны предметам. А краткие прилагательные чаще всего обозначают временный признак, который принадлежит предмету в конкретной ситуации

```
Он был мудр   // в данный момент
Он был мудрый // по жизни
```

Хотя на мой взгляд, в подобных примерах, иллюстрирующих различие момента, играет роль не столько краткость прилагательного, сколько падеж полного прилагательного. Сравните

```
Он был мудрый // по жизни
Он был мудрым // в данный момент
```

Comment: Так там три варианта, а не два.

Comment: Вы ничего не сказали про "к".